How to Automatically Run an APK from an SD Card on Arduino Pro Micro when Connected to Android via OTG?
I want to run an APK file that is stored on an SD card connected to an Arduino Pro Micro, once the Arduino is connected to my Android phone via OTG.
Is there a way to automatically trigger and run the APK file located on the SD card when the Arduino is plugged into the Android phone?
I’ve tried some approaches but haven’t been able to achieve this yet. Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide any relevant guidance?

There is no concept in Android of "run an APK file". You can install an app from an APK file. Is that what you mean?

Yes installing it and at the end I want to execute it.

looks like perfect scenario for quick installing "bad software" on random phones. that's not possible for 100%
you may configure your Arduino to act as pendrive/memory, but user would need to manually navigate to path and install APK. a bit easier would be with already (another) installed software on device - it may recognize your Arduino, get APK from it and request installation to Android, still user need to agree
there is no possibility to install APK on device without user accept, you can do such things only through ADB and device must have unlocked dev tools/debugging...
